# How to add excel column values when the column title changes

Tags: python, excel

So I want to add columns extracted from an excel sheet, however the column names may vary without me changing them.

I thought to use each column name as a variable and add the columns related top them but cannot make it work.

Initial basic code to add the columns

```
df1['Iem Value']= 100 + df1['Value']
print (df1)
```

Will give me something like this in the new (last column):

```
  Iem  Value  Value 2  Iem Value
0   A     12       10        112
1   b      2       10        102
2   c     45       10        145
3   d      6       10        106
4   e      3       10        103
```

Then if we make the columns as lists

```
col_list = df1.columns.values.tolist()
print(col_list)
```

['Iem', 'Value', 'Value 2', 'Iem Value']

Then how do you put these back into the original line adding 100?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "how do you put these back into the original line"?

Comment: Ho wdo you know what the name changes to? Is Iem4 sure to change to Iem6 or will it be Iem27 ? Do you have a table of old to new names?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "how do you put these back into the original line"? – 
Grismar
 
Yes, I mean how to put the variable of the sheet name back to this line

df1['****new variabel here***']= 100 + df1['Value']
print (df1)

Comment: And the table is not under my control and others change names regardless!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding how your obtaining/implementing code however perhaps the following scenario may help get you on track;

I'm guessing your using pandas so if we assume your table has the columns *'Iem', 'Value', 'Value 2', 'Iem Value'*, the df1 columns list will contain those values (and display as above when **print(df1.columns)** is executed). The unknown/variable column 'Iem Value' is the last element of that list so this can be assigned to the variable *unknown_col_name* by the line **unknown_col_name = df1.columns[-1]**. The variable can then be used in your calculation line **df1[unknown_col_name] = 100 + df1['Value']**
NOTE variable has no quotes surrounding it.

```
...
print(df1.columns) # prints  ...'Unnamed: 0', 'Iem', 'Value', 'Value 2', 'Iem Value'...

# assign variable unknown_col_name to last element in df1.columns, 'Iem Value'
unknown_col_name = df1.columns[-1] # assumes the last element is required column name

df1[unknown_col_name] = 100 + df1['Value'] # performs calc with column 'Value' in the unknown named column
print (df1) # prints table as shown in question

col_list = df1.columns.values.tolist()
print(col_list) # ['Unnamed: 0', 'Iem', 'Value', 'Value 2', 'Iem Value']
```

The unknown column name may not be the last in the list if there are other headers following so it may be necessary to loop through the list instead or if you obtain the name of the unknown column some other way you should still be able to assign to the variable to use in that line.